# Projectile exploding in two masses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

I'm working on the following problem:

> A projectile with a mass  and a velocity $(=0)=0$ explodes into two pieces. The energy gain from the explosion is . What is the ideal mass distribution so that for one of the particles
>
> a) The kinetic energy is maximised.
> b) The velocity is maximised.
> c) The momentum is maximised

When i first started to think about it, it seems that the mass distribution should be such that one particle has an infinitely small mass and one a mass that approaches the original mass for (a) and (b).

It seems strange to get such an answer, though. Am i making a mistake? Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: You have two relations, energy and momentum conservation, and one free variable, *y=m/M* where *m* is the not heavier mass. You wish to find the maxima of 3 functions of *y*. Can you think of a cannon or a rifle? What about your fine answer bothers you?

Comment: Please explain your reasoning. How did you get your answer? Why do you think your answer is "strange"?

Comment: I considered that momentum must be conserved, so (m_1)(v_1)=-(m_2)(v_2). Energy is distributed according to (m_1)/2*(v_1)^2+(m_2)/2*(v_2)^2=E. When i decrease the mass of one particle, according to the momentum conservation its velocity will increase proportionally. According to the energy formula, its kinetic energy will increase exponentially. Is this correct? Usually my professor gives us assignments where we get a formula or a value as an answer, infinity just feels... "cheap". Maybe my gut feeling is off on this one.

Answer (score 0):

(c) The momenta will be equal $(p_1=p_2=p)$ regardless of mass distribution. This follows from conservation of momentum.

(b) The velocity of one part is maximum when its mass is much less than that of the other. Again this follows from conservation of momentum : $m_1 v_1 = m_2 v_2$ therefore $v_1 \gg v_2$ if $m_1 \ll m_2$.

(a) The kinetic energies are $K_1=\frac{p^2}{2m_1}, K_2=\frac{p^2}{2m_2}$ so they are in the ratio $\frac{K_1}{K_2}=\frac{m_2}{m_1}$. To get $K_1 \gg K_2$ we need $m_1 \ll m_2$, which is the same requirement as for maximising velocity.